# Star Trek: First Contact -- any stories about assimilation of Earth?

Tags: star-trek, fan-fiction, star-trek-first-contact

Per the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact):

> The Borg sphere generates and enters a temporal vortex. As the Enterprise is enveloped in the vortex, **the crew briefly glimpses an Earth populated entirely by Borg. Picard realizes that the Borg have used time travel to change history**, and orders the Enterprise to follow.
>
> [image]

I was always intrigued by this alternate history. Does anyone know of anything that further describes events <strike>leading up to</strike>, during, or after the assimilation of Earth? Whether it's canon or not--or fan fiction--I'm not so concerned with. I just would like a good story!

Specifically I'm kind of looking for something from the perspective of those on the planet. The interesting geographical changes from this image make we want to know so much more.

Comment: Mentioned in 'Engines of Destiny'; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_history

Comment: @Valorum I'll look into it! Though it doesn't seem like I'll get the whole story but this is more than I was able to find.

Comment: It was also briefly mentioned in an episode of ST:VOY.  I don't recall the episode title, but Neelix and another character were playing a game of trivia, and the subject of Zeprham Cochrane's first warp flight came up.  Specifically, the question related to the name of his ship.  Seven of Nine came up with the answer and when asked how she knew it, she said "The Borg were present at those events".

Comment: There is also a mention about Zephram Cochrane mentioning Borg in ST:ENT. It was even a two- or three-episode story involving Borg drones found in ice or permafrost somewhere.

Comment: @AcePL Right that sounds familiar. Though that is referring to the actual events occurred in the 'prime' timeline. I'm referring to the events that didn't happen due to Picard's intervention in First Contact. Though it's sounding like what I'm looking for doesn't really exist.

Comment: Actually, this won't be a 'prime timeline'... Else in "Encounter at Farpoint" Picard would not be so polite to the first drones appearing on his bridge...

Comment: Based on the color, I'd say that arrow is pointed at a nasty, disgusting cloud - its meteorological not geological.

Comment: Remember: a cannon is a weapon.

Answer (score 2):

While not specific to the encounter of First Contact. There was a comic called the Worst of Both Worlds. Where the Enterprise failed to stop the Borg in an alternate reality. I no longer have the book, but the Enterprise from the TV series was pulled into this alternate reality. And while I don't know if a date is given how long after the battle of Wolf 359 this is happening, there are still humans being assimilated and human resistance.

I checked Memory Beta, and the article about the comic is unfortiunately lacking. http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Worst_of_Both_Worlds_(comic)

As to the brown blob the arrow points to, that appears simply to be clouds, the same colour seems to be seen over North America.

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of Star Trek novels written by William Shatner that were written in the Mirror universe. The last one either said or strongly implied that the origin of the Mirror universe was the invasion of the Borg. I still remember the "OMG that's so cool!" moment when he put those pieces together that way.

He's a surprisingly good storyteller (plus he has help from more prominent Star Trek authors as co-writers). The first three novels (The Ashes of Eden, The Return, and Avenger) are Kirk's return after his death in Generations. The next three (Spectre, Dark Victory, and Preserver) are the Mirror Universe ones. I remember the Borg were prominent in many of those. He has three more in the series, but I don't remember what they were about, and then a few that weren't part of the "Shatnerverse". Plus he has written novels that aren't part of Star Trek (the TekWar series, and a couple one-offs).

Comment: So do the books you refer to tell about the assimilation of Earth by the Borg?

Comment: If the original question was about a story that took place in a universe where that assimilation was successful, then this wouldn't apply. I was keying off of the "or after the assimilation of Earth" part of the question. This is more about what effect such an attempt would have on the development of the new space-faring culture on Earth.

Comment: “Shatnerverse”— I think we say Shatverse.